# PHP - Needle in a haystack search not working when surrounded by similar hay stacks

Tags: php, regex, scrape, scraper

Anyone know how to modify the scraper below to achieve the desired result:

```
Array ( [0] => Gold_Needle [1] => Silver_Needle )
```

The code can be ran online @ http://ideone.com/QATj5a

Result is:

```
Array ( [0] => this is a bunch of hay hay1= Gold_Needle [1] => Silver_Needle )
```

**Desired** Result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Gold_Needle [1] => Silver_Needle )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$starts` and `$ends` array to build a lookahead regex like this:

```
(hay1=\h*\K(?:.(?!hay1))*?(?= hay=Gold))|(hay2=\h*\K(?:.(?!hay2))*?(?= hay=Silver))
```

- [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV6zQ0/3)
- [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/Fk4xYL)

**Code:**

```
$haystack='Data set 1: hay2= this is a bunch of hay  hay1= Gold_Needle hay=Gold
             Data Set 2: hay2=Silver_Needle hay=Silver';

$needle1_Begin='hay1=';
$needle2_Begin='hay2=';

$needle1_End='hay=Gold';
$needle2_End='hay=Silver';

$starts = array($needle1_Begin,$needle2_Begin);
$ends = array($needle1_End,$needle2_End);

$re = array_reduce($starts, function($res, $e) use (&$ends) {
    $res .= '(' . $e . '\h*\K(?:.(?!' . $e . '))*?(?= ' . current($ends) . '))|';
    next($ends); return $res;} );

$re = '/' . substr($re, 0, -1) . '/';

if (preg_match_all($re, $haystack, $m))
   print_r($m[0]);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Gold_Needle
    [1] => Silver_Needle
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!  The "starts" and "ends" in the code will be variables, such as I put in the edited code @ http://ideone.com/QATj5a.    Like these:                                                                          $needle1_Begin='hay1=';
$needle2_Begin='hay2=';
   
$needle1_End='hay=Gold';
$needle2_End='hay=Silver';                                                                                     So I am not sure about putting them inside the regex. The number of these variables will grow. There could be dozens like $needle55_Begin and so on.  Ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: btw, I have a really hard [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406286/how-to-prevent-of-re-replacing-by-second-regex). You have a gold-regex-badge, may you please take a look at it? *(beforehand)* thanks.

Comment: @ven: Check updated answer with full code. Regex remains same but some PHP coding was required to build the regex.