# How to prevent of re-replacing by second regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, hyperlink

I have two regex(s) on the way of my input, these:

```
// replace a URL with a link which is like this pattern: [LinkName](LinkAddress)
$str= preg_replace("/\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)/", "<a href='$2' target='_blank'>$1</a>", $str);

// replace a regular URL with a link
$str = preg_replace("/(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i","<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">untitled</a>", $str);
```

Now there is a problem *(somehow a collision)*. For regular URLs everything is fine. But for a pattern-based URLs, there is a problem: The first regex create a link of that and second regex **again** create a link of its `href`-attribute value.

How can I fix it?

**Edit:** According to the comments, how can I create a single regex instead of those two regex? *(using `preg_replace_callback`)*. Honestly I tried it but it doesn't work for none kind of URLs ..

Is combining them possible? Because the output of those isn't identical. The first one has a LinkName and the second one has a constant string `untitled` as its LinkName.

Comment: build a single pattern for the two cases (with an alternation `|`) and use `preg_replace_callback`. In the callback function, you must determine (with available capture groups) which one has been found. In this way the string is parsed only once.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for your comment. I did it but it doesn't work for none of those kind of URLs.

Comment: @stack Then show us what you tried. We can't debug blind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)|(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i', 
function($matches) {
    if(isset($matches[3])) {
        // replace a regular URL with a link
        return "<a href='".$matches[3]."' target='_blank'>untitled</a>";
    } else {
        // replace a URL with a link which is like this pattern: [LinkName](LinkAddress)
        return "<a href=".$matches[2]." target='_blank'>".$matches[1]."</a>";
    }
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

One way would be to do it like this. You merge your two expressions together with the alternative character `|`. Then in your callback function you just check if your third capture group is set (`isset($matches[3])`) and if yes, then your second regular expression matched the string and you replace a normal link, otherwise you replace with link/linktext.

I hope you understand everything and I could help you.

Comment: Perfect ...! That's exactly what I needed. +1